# How to switch from d3.svg.line to a choice that allows different coloured segments?

Tags: d3.js

Is there an easy way to draw the line chart, using `d3.svg.line`, such that you can specify the colour of each segment individually? Or a slot-in replacement for `d3.svg.line` that allows this kind of control?

My start point was basically this example:
https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642874

I tried this first:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d, i) { return x(i); })
.y(function(d, i) { return y(d.v); })
.style("stroke",function(d){return d>0?"#f00":#0f0";})
;
```

But it got a *function not found* complaint.

Then I tried:

```
var path = svg.append("g")
.attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
.append("path")
.data([data])
.attr("class", "line")
.style('stroke',function(d,i){return (d>0?'#f00':'#0f0');})
.attr("d", line)
;
```

But that just gave me all green lines (It turns out `d` is not my data).

This is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10504237/841830) from a couple of years ago, which says "not now, maybe soon". I tried looking at the cool examples like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4163057) and [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4165404) but cannot work out how to relate their code to the code I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no drop-in replacement. You have two options for making lines with different coloured segments.

1. Create the line segments separately.
2. Use a gradient fill with hard stops to create the illusion of different segments.

For the former, there's a very nice answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219557/how-to-draw-different-color-path-between-center-and-different-nodes-in-d3-js) that gives more details. The latter way I've used in [this visualisation](http://www.larsko.org/v/euca/).